# Unable to change the top level title of documentation and unable to submit review

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, documentation

[react-route v4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) is recently released. [The documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/react-router/5546/getting-started-with-react-router) on SO was written for v3.

I wanted to edit the title from  `Getting started with react-router` to `Getting started with react-router v3` but it does not let me.

[image]

Since I am not able to change it, I cannot submit a review for discussion

[image]

The error message

[image]

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the Introductory Topic is generated automatically from the tag's friendly name:

> ### Getting started with $tag

The tag friendly name is editable in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/106942):

[image: Tag wiki]

I updated the friendly name to "React Router", which I believe is more accurate.

If an example only works for v3, you might consider using [inline versions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions) or changing the title of the example itself. The intro topic itself (unlike other topics) can't be limited to a specific version, however. Some tags have separate topics to go into more detail about installation, which might help here.